# Service conductors between meter box and 100 panel. Can I still use #2 Aluminum? Manitoba

Tags: wiring

Can I still use #2 Alum between meter box and 100 amp panel? Meter box is on the side of the house and panel is at the back.

Comment: What type of insulation is on this #2 Al, and can we assume it's a cable or in conduit?  Also, is this an indoor or an outdoor panel?

Comment: In the U.S. #2 aluminum is good from 75,90,100 amp services depending on temp. The 75 degree / 90 Amp is the standard but not sure in manatoba.

Answer (score 1):

The 23rd edition of the Canadian Electrical Code allows 2AWG aluminum service conductors for a 100A service if the conductor insulation is rated to 90˚C and the conductors terminate on equipment with maximum conductor termination temp of 75˚C (which includes all modern circuit breakers).

These service conductors must also be carried in a minimum 1.25" conduit. If it's PVC conduit, the conduit must carry an SR (Sunlight Resistant) designation stamped on the outside.

Comment: Thanks for all your answers. Andy would you have the code # which allows 90C wire to terminate in the 75C equipment with down rating the conductor?They tell me I have to down rate my 90C conductor to 75C because it terminate in 75C conductor. Doesn't make sense to me because that is just equipment rating.

Comment: I have a guide book for Canadian provinces including MB that states: "For 3-wire 120/240V and 120/208V service conductors for single dwellings, or feeder conductors supplying single dwelling units of row housing of apartment and similar buildings, and that are sized according to Rules 8-200(1), 8-200(2), and 8-202(1), the allowable ampacity for copper and aluminum conductors with 90˚C insulation that terminate on equipment with a maximum termination temp of 75˚C is as follows: … Aluminum No 2 AWG  - 100A". Of course, the inspector generally has the last word….

Comment: Also see http://www.southwire.ca/en/products/rwu.htm